# AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling CRF.call(). module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'dot'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I was building Bi-LSTM CRF to do NER task. When it comes to

```
history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    np.array(y_train),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_split=0.1,
    callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

The error pop up

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-f7b1ef4826d9> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2     X_train,
      3     np.array(y_train),
      4     batch_size=batch_size,
      5     epochs=epochs,

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_contrib/layers/crf.py in viterbi_decoding(self, X, mask)
    557 
    558     def viterbi_decoding(self, X, mask=None):
--> 559         input_energy = self.activation(K.dot(X, self.kernel) + self.bias)
    560         if self.use_boundary:
    561             input_energy = self.add_boundary_energy(

AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling CRF.call().

module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'dot'

Arguments received by CRF.call():
  • X=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3000, 3), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
```

My full code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aXLk-dz9WqZD-axCRRl6927xFwN50xEa?usp=sharing)

I already updated to the newest tensorflow and keras and already import those library

my tensorflow version is 2.15.0

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Have u found any fix..?? I am facing the same issue. I assume the error is due to version conflicts!

Comment: no i haven't, instead i found a new notebook for bi-lstm crf in Kaggle